# require_once function showing fatal error and warning

Tags: php, function

hello i m working with PHP and i want to include a class.php file from my classes folder into one of my page but it showing error that:

> Warning:
>   require_once(/usr/home/shantak5/public_html/gman/classes/globalProgram.class.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /usr/home/shantak5/public_html/gman/adminGlobalProgram.php on line 18
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required
>   '/usr/home/shantak5/public_html/gman/classes/globalProgram.class.php'
>   (include_path='/usr/home/shantak5/public_html/gman/PEAR') in
>   /usr/home/shantak5/public_html/gman/adminGlobalProgram.php on line 18

i m unable to know what is the wrong with my code.my .class.php file is in Classes folder.

Here is my php code for adminglobalprogram.php where i add the require once function.:

```
<?php
require 'config.inc.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(!$_SESSION['isLogged'])
header("Location: index.php");

if(isset($_GET['hid']) && $_GET['hid'] == 1){
$show = "yes";
}else{
    $show = "no";
}
if(isset($_GET['mod'])){
$update = "yes";
$itemId = $_GET['mod'];
}else{
    $update = "no";
}

require_once(APP_CLASS_PATH."globalProgram.class.php");
$objForm            = new pevcProgram;
$message = "";


if(isset($_POST['saveProgram'])){

                $timeval = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['timeval']);
                $timeheading = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['timeheading']);
                $descriptionheading = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriptionheading']);
                $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
                $description=stripslashes($description);
                $descriptionheading1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriptionheading1']);
                $description1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description1']);
                $description1=stripslashes($description1);
                $descriptionheading2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriptionheading2']);
                $description2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description2']);
                $description2 =stripslashes($description2);
                $descriptionheading3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriptionheading3']);
                $description3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description3']);
                $description3 =stripslashes($description3);
                $image = $_FILES['image']['name']; 
                if($flag !== 0){                
                if(!empty($image)){
                $bgSource   = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
                $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($image, "."), 1));
                if($ext == "png" || $ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg" ){

                /* Open This code
                $imgpathD   = 'photos/'.topBarBgtest.".$ext";
                $imgpath    = './photos/'.topBarBgtest.".$ext";
                */
                $imgpathD   = 'photos/program/'.'Global_'.$image;
                $imgpath    = './photos/program/'.'Global_'.$image;

                if(move_uploaded_file($bgSource, $imgpath)){
                //$message .= "Image successfully uploaded.<br />";
                }else{
                $flag = 0;
                }
                }else{
                $flag = 0;
                }
                }
                }

                //$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FCKeditor1']);
                $line = $_POST['line'];
                $srorder = $_POST['srorder'];
                $status = $_POST['status'];

                $fieldInfo  = array(
                                         'timeval'      => $timeval,
                                         'timeheading'  => $timeheading,
                                         'descriptionheading'=>$descriptionheading,
                                         'description'   => $description,
                                         'descriptionheading1'=>$descriptionheading1,
                                         'description1'   => $description1,
                                         'descriptionheading2'=>$descriptionheading2,
                                         'description2'   => $description2,
                                         'descriptionheading3'=>$descriptionheading3,
                                         'description3'   => $description3,
                                         'image'           => $image,
                                         'line'         => $line,
                                         'srorder'      => $srorder,
                                         'status'       => $status);
                $recId      = $objForm->addFormField($fieldInfo);
                if(isset($recId) && $recId != ""){                  
                $message .= "Form successfully saved!!.<br />";
                }else{
                $message .= "Error!Form data not saved.Please try again!!.<br />";
                }
                }

if(isset($_POST['update']))

          {
                //$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FCKeditor1']);
                $timeval = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['timeval']);
                $timeheading = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['timeheading']);
                $descriptionheading = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriptionheading']);
                $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
                $description=stripslashes($description);
                $line = $_POST['line'];
                $descriptionheading1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriptionheading1']);
                $description1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description1']);
                $description1 =stripslashes($description1);
                $descriptionheading2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriptionheading2']);
                $description2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description2']);
                $description2 =stripslashes($description2);
                $descriptionheading3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriptionheading3']);
                $description3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description3']);
                $description3 =stripslashes($description3);

                //image uploade//   

                $image = $_FILES['image']['name']; 
                if($flag !== 0){                
                if(!empty($image)){
                $bgSource   = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
                $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($image, "."), 1));
                if($ext == "png" || $ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg" ){

                /* Open This code
                $imgpathD   = 'photos/'.topBarBgtest.".$ext";
                $imgpath    = './photos/'.topBarBgtest.".$ext";
                */
                $imgpathD   = 'photos/program/'.'Global_'.$image;
                $imgpath    = './photos/program/'.'Global_'.$image;
                if(move_uploaded_file($bgSource, $imgpath)){
                //$message .= "Image successfully uploaded.<br />";
                }else{
                $flag = 0;
                }
                }else{
                $flag = 0;
                }
                }
                }

                $srorder = $_POST['srorder'];
                $status = $_POST['status'];
                $updId = $_POST['updId'];

                $fieldInfo      = array('timeval'   => $timeval,
                                        'timeheading'   => $timeheading,
                                        'descriptionheading'=>$descriptionheading,
                                        'description'   => $description,
                                        'descriptionheading1'=>$descriptionheading1,
                                        'description1'   => $description1,
                                        'descriptionheading2'=>$descriptionheading2,
                                        'description2'   => $description2,
                                        'descriptionheading3'=>$descriptionheading3,
                                        'description3'   => $description3,
                                        'image'           => $image,
                                         'line'     => $line,
                                         'srorder'  => $srorder,
                                         'status'   => $status);
                $recId      = $objForm->updateFormInfo($updId,$fieldInfo);
                if(isset($recId) && $recId != "")
                {                   
                $message .= "Form successfully updated!!.<br />";
                }else
                {
                $message .= "Error!Form data not updated.Please try again!!.<br />";
                }
            }
                /*unset($_GET['update']);*/

/* srorder update accroding text input*/    


if(isset($_POST['textsubmit']))
          {
                //$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FCKeditor1']);
                $timeval = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['timeval']);
                $timeheading = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['timeheading']);
                $descriptionheading = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriptionheading']);
                $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
                $description=stripslashes($description);

                $descriptionheading1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriptionheading1']);
                $description1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description1']);
                $description1 =stripslashes($description1);
                $descriptionheading2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriptionheading2']);
                $description2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description2']);
                $description2 =stripslashes($description2);
                $descriptionheading3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriptionheading3']);
                $description3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description3']);
                $description3 =stripslashes($description3);

                //image uploade//   

                $image = $_FILES['image']['name']; 
                if($flag !== 0){                
                if(!empty($image)){
                $bgSource   = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
                $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($image, "."), 1));
                if($ext == "png" || $ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg" ){

                /* Open This code
                $imgpathD   = 'photos/'.topBarBgtest.".$ext";
                $imgpath    = './photos/'.topBarBgtest.".$ext";
                */
                $imgpathD   = 'photos/program/'.'Global_'.$image;
                $imgpath    = './photos/program/'.'Global_'.$image;

                if(move_uploaded_file($bgSource, $imgpath)){
                //$message .= "Image successfully uploaded.<br />";
                }else{
                $flag = 0;
                }
                }else{
                $flag = 0;
                }
                }
                }
                $line = $_POST['line'];
                $srorder = $_POST['srorder'];
                $status = $_POST['status'];
                $updId = $_POST['updId'];

                $fieldInfo      = array('timeval'   => $timeval,
                                        'timeheading'   => $timeheading,
                                        'descriptionheading'=>$descriptionheading,
                                        'description'   => $description,
                                        'descriptionheading1'=>$descriptionheading1,
                                        'description1'   => $description1,
                                        'descriptionheading2'=>$descriptionheading2,
                                        'description2'   => $description2,
                                        'descriptionheading3'=>$descriptionheading3,
                                        'description3'   => $description3,
                                        'image'           => $image,
                                         'line'     => $line,
                                         'srorder'  => $srorder,
                                         'status'   => $status);
                $recId      = $objForm->updateFormInfo($updId,$fieldInfo);
                if(isset($recId) && $recId != "")
                {                   
                $message .= "Form successfully updated!!.<br />";
                }else
                {
                $message .= "Error!Form data not updated.Please try again!!.<br />";
                }
            }




if(isset($_GET['Rmod'])){
$itemId = $_GET['Rmod'];        
$formretu   = $objForm->deleteRec($itemId);
if($formretu){
$message .= "Record successfully Deleted!!.<br />"; 
    }else{
    $message .= "Record not Deleted!!.<br />";  
        }
}       


if($update == "yes"){
$formArr    = $objForm->getFormInfo($itemId);               
$timeval    = $formArr->timeval;
//$content      = $formArr->content;
//$content = stripslashes($content);
$timeheading            = $formArr->timeheading;
$descriptionheading     = $formArr->descriptionheading;
$description            = $formArr->description;
$descriptionheading1    = $formArr->descriptionheading1;
$description1           = $formArr->description1;
$descriptionheading2    = $formArr->descriptionheading2;
$description2           = $formArr->description2;
$descriptionheading3    = $formArr->descriptionheading3;
$description3           = $formArr->description3;
$image                  = $formArr->image;
$line                   = $formArr->line;
$srorder                = $formArr->srorder;
$status                 = $formArr->status;
}
$asiaArr        = $objForm->getAllAsiaProg1();
$upNUM      = $objForm->isRecord();
$upNUM      = $upNUM;
$recNum     = $objForm->isRecord();     
$recNum = $recNum + 1;
//print_r($_SESSION); 
$smarty->assign('show', $show);
$smarty->assign('update', $update);
$smarty->assign('timeval', $timeval);
$smarty->assign('timeheading', $timeheading);
$smarty->assign('descriptionheading', $descriptionheading);
$smarty->assign('description', $description);
$smarty->assign('descriptionheading1', $descriptionheading1);
$smarty->assign('description1', $description1);
$smarty->assign('descriptionheading2', $descriptionheading2);
$smarty->assign('description2', $description2);
$smarty->assign('descriptionheading3', $descriptionheading3);
$smarty->assign('description3', $description3);

$smarty->assign('image', $image);
//$smarty->assign('content', $content);
$smarty->assign('line', $line);
$smarty->assign('srorder', $srorder);
$smarty->assign('status', $status);
$smarty->assign('asiaArr', $asiaArr);
$smarty->assign('itemId', $itemId);
$smarty->assign('upNUM', $upNUM);
$smarty->assign('recNum', $recNum);
//$smarty->assign('content', $newContent);

$smarty->assign('message', $message);
//$smarty->assign('sno', $sno);
$smarty->display('adminGlobalProgram.tpl');
?>
```

Comment: Simple case of file not being found as defined inside `require_once`

Comment: Folder name is `classes` or `Classes`?

Comment: Can you show us output of "echo APP_CLASS_PATH;" ? If you are using relative path, try absolute.

Comment: the folder name is classes

Comment: in my admin area there is a link from where i add the details of a page. when i click on that link it takes me to adminGlobalProgram.php page in which i have use this require once function. so can u tell me that whats going wrong here??? i m newby to PHP plzz guys help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs only when,

> 1) Your file is not located in the defined location.
>
> 2) There is a name conflict between the mentioned file and located
>   file.
>
> 3) There is any case sensitive letters in the file.

Please check the above in your case

Answer (score 2):

Isnt it so simple?

`/usr/home/shantak5/public_html/gman/classes/globalProgram.class.php`

This file: `globalProgram.class.php` 
is not present here : `/usr/home/shantak5/public_html/gman/classes/`.

Comment: but i just upload the file at this folder and it still showing this error..:(

Comment: check for spelling mistakes or case mistakes

Comment: hey bro i just want to know that in my local system the class folder path is Z:\globalMA\2010\classes\file.class.php and when i upload it to my server the path is /usr/home/shantak5/public_html/gman/classes

Comment: If the classes directory and the file are both there, are they even accessible? check for Permissions

Comment: The error said `no such file/directory` not about permission I guess... So I think you just need to re-double-check again... Or  try to put `echo 'Hello';` on top of `globalProgram.class.php`, and try to open that file from http.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for ur concern but i fixed it now.it was a silly mistake....:( i just type the file name wrong as globalProgram.class.php instead of globalprogram.class.php

Comment: but now i m facing a new problem guys now i m able to go inside the page but my left sidebar is not showing ther and instead of that its shooowing the error as:

Smarty error: unable to read resource: "adminGlobalMA_left.tpl" in /usr/home/shantak5/public_html/gman/smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1093